# I receive permission denied for the shell I have built

Tags: c, shell, process, argv, fork

I have created a shell and I have parsed the input I take from the command prompt using strtok with the  space delimiter.  I don't know why for specific commands like `ls` or `ls -l` it is not working while it is working for "cp x y" command. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <assert.h>

void execute(char **argv)
{
  int status;
  int pid = fork();
  if (pid  <0)  //fork error has happened
     {
       perror("Can't fork a child process\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
  if (pid==0)   //It's the child process and can run his task
     {
    execvp(argv[0],argv); 
        perror("error");  
     }
  else  //pid>0 it's the parent and should wait for the child
     {
        int status;
       // int wc = wait(&status);
       // assert(wc != -1);

      //while(wait(&status)!=pid) 
      //   ;
        wait(NULL);  //the way taught in the class
     }


}

int main (int argc, char **argv)

{
   char input[256];
   char *args[256];
   char **next = args;
   char *temp;
   while (1)
   {
      printf("mysh>");
      fgets(input,256,stdin);
      input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;
      if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit\n")==0)
             exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      else
         {
              temp = strtok(input, " ");
              while(temp != NULL)
                  {
                     printf("%s\n", temp);
                     *next++ = temp;
                     temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
                  }      
              *next = NULL;

              execute(args);
             //execvp(args[0],args);  //When I put this command here it just runs once though it is in a while loop so we have to use fork!

         }

   }

   return 0;


}
```

and here's a demo of its run:

```
 ./basic_shell 
mysh>ls
ls
basic_shell  basic_shell.c  basic_shell.c~  basic_shell_OK.c  fork  fork.c
mysh>ls
ls
ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory
mysh>ls
ls
ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory
mysh>ls
ls
ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory
```

And when I execute cp command it works as following:

```
./basic_shell 
mysh>cp fork.c fork_cp.c
cp
fork.c
fork_cp.c
mysh>cp fork_cp.c copy_fork.c
cp
fork_cp.c
copy_fork.c
cp: target `copy_fork.c' is not a directory
```

Can you please guide me why is my shell acting kind of awkwardly and unexpectedly?

Answer (score 1):

You have two calls to `fork`

```
int pid = fork();
if ((pid = fork()) <0)
```

Only one is enough. The first one.

As for the errors, you strings contain the `\n` terminator which you need to remove first. After doing `fgets(input,256,stdin);`, assuming that you'll never type more than 255 characters in a line you should do

```
input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;
```

to remove the `\n`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that fork() thing. For the nullifying thing, what you said didn't work and I have the following error: fgets(input,256,stdin);
 stdin[strlen(stdin) - 1] = 0;
`basic_shell.c: In function ‘main’:
basic_shell.c:48: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/string.h:399: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct _IO_FILE *’
basic_shell.c:48: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct _IO_FILE’ from type ‘int’
`

Comment: My bad, it should have been `input`, not `stdin`. Reworded the answer.

Comment: Yes, it should have been changed twice. I must go to sleep :) Thanks

Comment: doing so I have this problem :
`mysh>ls
ls
basic_shell    basic_shell.c~  code.c?  fork.c  mysh.c pa   strtok
basic_shell.c  basic_shell_OK.c  fork   mysh   new_shell.c? pointer_array.c  strtok.c
mysh>ls
ls
ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory`